# Mysql вывод данных связанных таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

нужна помощь в запросе MySql.
Есть таблица people:

```
id
name
```

Во второй таблице хранятся поля (столбцы), таблица Б

```
id
people_id
field_name
field_value
```

Содержит такую информацию:

```
1|1|gender|m
2|1|age|12
3|1|FIO|Ivanov
```

Вопрос, как сделать запросом, строки перевести в столбцы, что бы был такой результат выполнения из двух связанных таблиц:

```
id|name|gender|age|FIO
```

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be-sql#1035)

Comment: Читайте про работу с EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) - чисто ваш случай.

Comment: Спасибо, EAV то что надо